# Why are SearchKit links blank if a data item is missing?

Tags: searchkit

I am recreating some Drupal Views in SearchKit and it has gone well except for one thing - links.  I'm not sure if what I am experiencing is a feature or a bug hence the question.

Our Views allow a user to click on a link that takes them to a Drupal Webform, often to complete or continue a process.  The link uses various data items such as Contact IDs and Activity IDs to populate the target form.

If I create what is effectively the same View in SearchKit the link will not be output if any data item or items in the link is/are missing (and it may well be null at that point for good reasons).

To illustrate, lets say I have a link defined like this:

```
civicrm/my_form?case1=[id]&cid2=[some_contact]&cid3=[another_contact]&activity1=[some_activity]
```

If, say, cid3 has no data for that record, the entire link will not be displayed in either a list or a table for that particular line.  A drupal View will just pass the link on with cid3 having no data, which is fine for our purposes:
`civicrm/my_form?case1=1234&cid2=123456&cid3=&activity1=54321`

I have tried experimenting with the 'Show if' but whatever I put there, that line never displays. As an example I set the Show if to display if the case ID was > 1 (it always would be on a View that displays cases) but this had no effect.

Am I missing a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like an oversight or scenario that hasn't been tested.  Create an issue at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues

Comment: Thanks Aidan - https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4222